# Android: creating a custom menu on the bottom

Tags: android, menu

I would like to create a custom made menu on the bottom of the screen, This menu will be as buttons and, it will always be visible first, if the user scrolls down, it will be visible, and scrolls upp.

How is this possible?

Comment: if it's visible first, when will it then be invisible then - your question doesn't say? Can you clarify your question. You mean you want a floating menu that's always at the bottom of the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this menu always visible? or does it only appear when the "menu" button is pressed?

An easy way to do this is to use a RelativeLayout as your main ViewGroup. Create a second ViewGroup (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout... or whatever) that contains your menu items and anchor the whole group to the bottom of the screen. If you were to then, put a ListView above that second group it would occupy all the space above your menu controls and the menu controls themselves would always be visible.

Hope that was helpful.

Comment: this menu is always visible, and will be used on some of the activities, do you have a tutorial?

Comment: unfortunately i dont have a website/blog for posting tutorials, and i dont have any code examples handy, but you should be able to google search for examples on how to use the RelativeLayout. once you know how to use the layout it should be easy to put one ViewGroup inside another.

Answer (score 0):

are using trying any thing similar to Tab View? use tabview and the end of the page by that u can always make use of that visible.. if you want it as button then go for listview and relative layout

Comment: How can I make the tabview to be shown at the end of the activity?

Comment: @troj:Have a relativelayout in our code, then add a listview to the layout then a tabview to the same layout.i hope this should do the job.whenever u click that tabview,load the dynamic content to listview.