# Anyone know how to create a custom menu like this in android apps?

Tags: android-layout

hii,I was just learning android i want create menu like this at this image
  [This Menu](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/717/custommenu.png/)

i was confused make this,anyody know how i can do it with 4 item like the link above ? 

please help me.

sory if my language english bad.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge custom menu and options menu can be modified (adding and removing menu items) easily.

If u want your own custom option menu, you may have to simulate by creating layouts.
1) Creative a layout and inflate the layout and show on clicking on the menu button.
2) If u want to occupy whole screen then better use Images and TextViews and create a new activity and launch the activity on clicking the options menu in  OnCreateOptionsMenu().

Please find the links below
[Custom menu in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119787/custom-menu-in-android)
[Android: creating a custom menu on the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039707/android-creating-a-custom-menu-on-the-bottom)